# FullCalendar get custom attribute value, update event attributes, feed JSON, AJAX post and JAVA servlet

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets, fullcalendar

I have came across a couple of problems finishing up my configuration of FullCalendar and communication with database.

After having read tons of documentations and posts in stackoverflow and elsewhere, I still have the problems mentioned in the my topic title.

I work on a project with a JAVA Web Application on Apache Tomcat and have successfully configured FullCalendar.

**1. How can I obtain my custom variable appid in order to make an ajax $.post()**

I do feed the calendar with values with the following binding on one of my views before the .JSP page is loaded with the following approach.

```
//More Code
events: ${appointments} 
//More Code
```

Data Sample:

```
    [
    {"title":"10","start":"2017-07-05T13:30:00","backgroundColor":"#009900"},{"title":"11","start":"2017-07-05T12:00:00","backgroundColor":"#009900"}
    ]
```

**2. Full Calendar Doesn't Fetch JSON**

Secondly, on another of my views trough an ajax post I retrieve my events from an SQLServer. I do format the JSON the same way as in my previous question and feed through doPost response with the following approach:

```
        response.setContentType("application/json");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

When tried to feed to the calendar through the data variable when I came across to a downside of FullCalendar which is "I can feed the data when I paste it to the `events.push()` manually but not automatically.

I read about this issue mentioning about the brackets. I have checked everything for more that half a day but no sight of success. Despite that at some point I managed to feed the calendar using the data variable only if it consisted one event. When I tried to add more while keeping the proper format I came against to the starting problem (JSON keeps in the same format as question 1, which is the proper one according to the posts that I've read)

This is my Ajax Post Request to the Servlet:

```
            $.post("/AppointmentServlet",
                {
                    selecteddoctorid: selectedDoctorID //This is relevant to my 1st question
                },

                function (data, status) {
                    var events = [];

                    //events.push(data);

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                }).change();
```

**3.Updating/Deleting event outside eventClick function failed**

Finally, after having made some changes in the database I want to change a few attributes of changed events, such as the color.

When I to attempt updating the event through the `eventClick` function of the Calendar everything works perfectly and the event is updated but when I tried to update inside the success function of the ajax post I see no change despite I tried the following things:

```
       function doSubmit() {
            $("#calendarModal").modal('hide');
            var title = $('#title').val();
            var eventId = $('#eventID').val();
            alert(eventId);
            var startTime = $('#startTime').val();

            $.post("/AppointmentServlet",
                {
                    appointmentid: appid
                },
                function (data, status) {
                alert(data);

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventid);


                }).change();
        }
```

I also had the same problem when I tried to delete the event using the following code:

```
                //This is part of an ajax post
                function (data, status) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventID);

                });
```

Comment: It's preferred to ask multiple question, one per problem, assuming all your woes can't be solved by a single change. But so far I don't really see why is this question tagged with Java. Do you have problems sending data from server?

Comment: No, not at all. Just wanted to let you know about my project setup.

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventid);` This method expects a whole event object, not just the ID, otherwise how will it know what the new values should be for all fields? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/

Comment: As for `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventID);` not working. Are you there's definitely an event with that ID on the calendar in the first place? Where are you getting the value of `eventID` from? Was it taken from the calendar/event data originally?